# Python 2.7.16 - Name not defined

Tags: python

I have the following code, however when I run it, the variable stored under employee_name is stated as "Name '[name inputted]' is not defined.
I've tried to comment it out, and the issue just arises with another line. Employee_num needs to be a string, as putting it as an integer claims it to not be iterable.
Can anyone help?

```
import time

ListNames = []
ListIDs = []
ListComissions = []
total_properties = 0
highest = 0
employee_num = "a"
employee_name = "aa"
employee_id= "a"
employee_properties = "a"
employee_comission = "a"

employee_num = str(input("Enter the number of employees: "))
for y in employee_num:
    employee_name = input("Enter the name of the employee: ")
    ListNames.append(employee_name)
    employee_id = str(input("Enter the ID of the employee: "))
    ListIDS.append(employee_id)
    employee_properties = int(input("Enter the number of properties sold by the employee: "))
    ListProperties.append(employee_properties)
    total_properties = total_properties + employee_properties
    employee_comission = employee_properties * 500
    ListComissions.append(employee_comission)
    total_comission = total_comission + employee_comission
for i in ListProperties:
    if ListProperties[i] > highest:
        highest = ListProperties[i]
    i = i + 1
star = ListProperties.index(highest)
print (ListNames[star])
print (ListIDs[star])
print (ListProperties[star])
print (ListComissions[star])
starcomission = ListComissions[star] + (ListComissions[star] * 0.15)
x = 1   
for x in employee_num:
    if x != star:
        print (ListNames[x])
        print (ListIDs[x])
        print (ListProperties[x])
        print (ListComissions[x])
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: You should use `raw_input` instead of `input` for Python 2, however I would recommend switching to Python 3 if you can

Comment: use `raw_input` instead of `input` (Or better yet, move to Python 3, Python 2 is no longer supported). `input` in Python 2 evaluates the expression passed.

Comment: `for x in employee_num` tries to iterate over `employee_num`. If you want to loop `employee_num` times, you should use `for x in range(employee_num)` and keep `employee_num` as an integer

Comment: Afraid I can't switch to Python 3, no matter how much I may want to. I will look into raw_input, however.
Let's hope it works!

Comment: @Sreckcep
Yeah, I tried that, it still failed.

Comment: @Silesviing I guess the earlier errors caused the interpreter to raise an exception before this code could execute, but your code still needs to be corrected in order to do what it is designed to do. Your code as it is will only loop one time, where `x` will have the value `employee_num` as a character.

Comment: There are so many problems in this code... Note that `for i in ListProperties: if ListProperties[i] > highest:` will not do what you expect and almost certainly raise `IndexError`

Comment: Raw input worked!
Issue is, listIDS has gotten a similar issue.

Comment: Is this some sort of school assignment?

Comment: @buran|
Got it, thanks. I'm not the best programmer, but I may as well fix the most immediate problems first.

Comment: That it is, college, ergo why I'm stuck on Python 2.

Comment: What college course would teach python2 3 years after python2 is not supported/EoL. That's insane

Comment: College computers have Python 2 installed, I requested a switch to 3. Here's hoping.

Comment: There is a college that still uses Python 2? Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020 and that was announced over 10 years ago. I have my doubts about the quality of this course. Do they also still teach that the sun orbits the earth?

Comment: Apparently so. Either the tech team is behind, incompetent or it's management. Still, beside the point.

Comment: listIDS is a capitalization error in line 19 of your code. You define it as ListIDs in line 4 of your code

Comment: Thanks, @JustinEdwards, I missed that one. That's one of the many issues down.